# Custom Auth system on Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

Well, I've just started using Laravel 5 and I've been told that he has an Authentication system (Auth), but it works for one Table. I have two kind of clients and each one has its own Table. and I need to Make a common Login Page, that checks both table ( assuming that usernames are unique in both tables). is there any solution for this ? Thanks

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46292391/authenticate-users-from-more-than-two-tables-in-laravel-5].  I guess this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You may add one more column of client type e.g. role in the same table and make  them able to login from the same view and then check in the postLogin Controller to see if they are of either role and give them the correct view.

Comment: Thank you, Actually I've thought of That but I have two different type of users.