# Authenticate users from more than two tables in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

As I know `Auth::attempt` is used to authenticate users from `users` table,  but i want to authenticate another users from `managers` table and admin from `admins` table. I know there are `laravel-multiauth` plugin already exist. But can we create our own `AuthServiceProvider` for authenticating users from multiple tables..?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First create Admin Authenticatable in `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth` like

```
    <?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

    class Admin extends Model implements
        AuthenticatableContract,
        AuthorizableContract,
        CanResetPasswordContract
    {
        use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;
    }
```

Then create Admin Model by extending  `Authenticatable` Admin Model :-

```
  <?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Admin as Authenticatable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

After that you need to modify `config/auth.php` like below 
Add in **providers** array

```
'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],
```

and Add in **guards** array.

```
 'user' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
 'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
```

Now to authenticate from **user** table

```
 if (Auth::guard('user')->attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        $details = Auth::guard('user')->user();
        $user = $details['original'];
        return $user;
    } else {
        return 'auth fail';
    }
```

And to authenticate from **Admin** table

```
 if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        $details = Auth::guard('admin')->user();
        $user = $details['original'];
        return $user;
    } else {
        return 'auth fail';
    }
```

Comment: Where should I put your last code? (for authentication)

Comment: Where should I put your last code? (for authentication)

Comment: You can put the above code in your LoginController

Comment: why do you need to create an Admin Authenticable? You can use the existing User Authenticable class...

Comment: where exactly the last two bits goes inside the LoginController??? as I try to put it anywhere and it throws me an error like I could not use an if statement anywhere

Comment: `$user = $details['original'];` is not working, but you can use `$user = $details->first();` or `$user = $details->all();` **(Laravel 8)**

Comment: This throws 419 | Page expired for me, even running cache clear.

Answer (score 17):

You could setup multiple authentication guards, with each one having a different provider. The providers define the table or model to be used.

In `config/auth.php` you setup the `providers` as follows and you also setup corresponding `guards` for each of those providers:

```
'providers' => [
    'users'  => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model'  => App\User::class,
    ],
    'managers'  => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model'  => App\Manager::class,
    ],
    'admins'  => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model'  => App\Admin::class,
    ]
]
```

Then you can authenticate like this:

```
Auth::attempt($credentials) // use default guard for simple users
Auth::guard('manager')->attempt($credentials)
Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($credentials)
```

Check out the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#authenticating-users).

Answer (score 7):

Try my idea if you want to. I'm expecting that different `table` has different `users`. Because it won't work if you have the same `user` in other tables.

1. Choose your priority table (e.g. users)
2. Add the condition

   - `if(Auth::user(attempt(...))`
   - `elseif(Auth::manager(attempt(...))`
   - `elseif(Auth::admins(attempt(...)))`

Note: Your priority table here is `users`, then if the user doesn't exists in that table, it will try the `managers` table, then if still doesn't exists, it will check the `admins` table, otherwise (use `else`) return a message error.

**Other option:**

Other option is to use this package `sarav/laravel-multiauth`. You can follow this thread. [How to use authentication for multiple tables in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29192535/how-to-use-authentication-for-multiple-tables-in-laravel-5#answer-32822341) for more information.

**More Reference:**

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/using-laravel-auth-for-multiple-tables?page=1

[Can anyone explain Laravel 5.2 Multi Auth with example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614753/can-anyone-explain-laravel-5-2-multi-auth-with-example)

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/52-auth-multiple-tables?page=1

Comment: thanks for the answer

Answer (score 4):

Create a model for managers table and admins table. This model should extend `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`

In `config/auth.php`,

Add to the providers array:

```
'managers' => [
    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model' => App\Manager::class,
 ],
```

Add to the guards array:

```
'web_manager' => [
    'driver' => 'session',
    'provider' => 'managers',
 ],
```

Then. in `LoginController` (create one for manager using `php artisan make:auth`) use the trait `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` and 
override  guard and redirect properties.

```
protected $redirectTo = 'redirect_path_after_manager_login';

protected function guard()
{
  return Auth::guard('web_manager');
}
```

The manager model is authenticated and you can get the auuthenticated manager's object  `Auth::guard('web_manager')->user();`