# Is there a way to authenticate the user in different databases in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am implementing access to different databases, but when using the middleware('auth:api') it says that I am not authenticated and when I login I get the token.

this only happens when the DB is not the default

im on laravel 5.8

```
public function login(LoginRequest $request, $db)
    {
        Config::set("database.connections.mysql.database", $db);
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])) {
            $this->user = Auth::user();
            $this->user->token = $this->user->createToken('ControlEscolar')->accessToken;
            $status = 200;
        } else {
            $this->user['error'] = "Unauthorized";
            $status = 401;
        }
        return response()->json($this->user, $status);
    }
```

---

```
public function userData($db)
    {
        Config::set("database.connections.mysql.database", $db);
        $user = userData::whereUserId(Auth::user()->id)
            ->first();
        return $user;
    }
```

on the login function i get this...

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "name of user",
    ...
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiO...CFU"
}
```

so it works

but in the second at user data i get this

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Unauthenticated.",
        "status_code": 500,
        "debug": {
            "line": 67,
            "file": "/Users/.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Auth\\AuthenticationException",
            ...
```

someone has a clue how to do it, or what am I doing wrong

Comment: Can you set your connection in `User` model like `protected $connection = 'connection-name';` and test?

Comment: I've already tried it, and it works, the problem is that it lets me use only a single BD, the other thing that tried was to duplicate the model and add what you recommend, but ... the idea of ​​the project is to connect to many BD , so it's not optimal

Comment: You want many tables of many database to represent one model?

Comment: is correct, the database has the same structure, I just need a way in which you can connect to all in a simple way, `Configure :: set ()` resolves it, the problem is the authenticated, is what I imagine

Comment: May be this will guide you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46292391/authenticate-users-from-more-than-two-tables-in-laravel-5

Comment: but its in the same bd :c

Comment: That doesn’t matter, that is using multiple models, you can use multiple models for multiple connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve it doing configure set on the route file like above:

```
$api->group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function (Router $api) {
    Config::set("database.connections.mysql.database", $db);
    $api->post('singup', 'App\\Api\\V1\\Controllers\\SignUpController@signUp');
});
```

> By de way i'm using dingo Api