# If my project has five different types of user then I have to create five different authentications?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.7

In Laravel, If my project has five different types of user then I have to create five different authentications?

Comment: you can use https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission

Comment: No need to different authentication. You can store your all users in 'users table' and use laravel role permission package. https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have five tables, then you can change Laravel that way to authenticate from five different tables.

Here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46292391/authenticate-users-from-more-than-two-tables-in-laravel-5) for the same.

if you are planning to build a system from scratch you can use laravel package for role management.

Here is package you can use for same.
 - [spatie/laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)

Comment: This is the best answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. You use a roles package that has roles, permissions, and levels, for laravel.
2. Give the users a role.
3. Assign different permissions to a role.
4. Use middleware to check on permission in either the routing files, the controller, or in a Request class.

If you google `laravel roles` you can find popular composer packages to use.