# Laravel 6.6 login credentials are wrong

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-6

I am trying to create a register and login pages using Laravel 6.6.0 register is working but login form not working if I add right login detail getting an error **'Wrong credentials please try again'** message and no errors can see.

**LoginController**

```php
class SISLoginController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('Front.SISLogin');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // Validate the user
        $rules = [
            'Email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ];
        $request->validate($rules);

        // Check if exists
        $data = request(['Email', 'password']);
        if (!auth()->attempt($data)) {
            return back()->withErrors([
                'message' => 'Wrong credentials please try again'
            ]);
        }

        return redirect('/SISprofile');
    }
}
```

**Model**

```php
class SISAccount extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function Evant()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Evants::class);
    }
}
```

**Edit: Form**

```
<form action="/SISLogin" method="POST" role="form" id="validate_form">
  @csrf
  <input type="text" class="form-control border" placeholder="Email" name="Email">
  <input type="password" class="form-control border" placeholder="Confirm-Password" name="password">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger text-uppercase w-100">Register</button>
```

Comment: Show your html form please.

Comment: ' <form action="/SISLogin" method="POST" role="form" id="validate_form">@csrf  
 <input type="text" class="form-control border" placeholder="Email" name="Email"> 
<input type="password" class="form-control border" placeholder="Confirm-Password" name="password"> 
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger text-uppercase w-100">Register</button>'

Comment: Could you please provide var_dump($data) ;

Comment: I pasted your form code in your question, you can `edit` your question yourself and paste any relevant data there if needed

Comment: @Dmitry problem was solved the problem was with my auth.php, thanks for you trying to help me

Comment: Please refer this if you're using different table for authenticating user, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46440975/4650866

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46292391/authenticate-users-from-more-than-two-tables-in-laravel-5/46440975#46440975